# Centering text in \adjustbox minipage with \hfill

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, adjustbox

I need to center text in a `adjustbox` package with a `minipage` keyword (see code below). I found I can do this by using two `\dotfill` or `\hrulefill` commands on either side of the text. Surprisingly, however, `\hfill` does not work.

I provide a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    {\bf These work as expected:}\\

    \vspace{2ex}
    \verb!{\dotfill{Foo}\dotfill}!\\
    \adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\dotfill{Foo}\dotfill}

    \vspace{2ex}
    \verb!{\hrulefill{Foo}\hrulefill}!\\
    \adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hrulefill{Foo}\hrulefill}

    \vspace{2ex}
    \verb!{\hfill{Foo}\hrulefill}!\\
    \adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hfill{Foo}\hrulefill}

    \vspace{5ex}
    {\bf These don't:}\\

    \vspace{2ex}
    \verb!{\hfill{Foo}\hfill}!\\
    \adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hfill{Foo}\hfill}

    \vspace{2ex}
    \verb!{\hrulefill{Foo}\hfill}!\\
    \adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hrulefill{Foo}\hfill}
\end{document}
```

My two questions are:

1. How can I center my text in a `\adjustbox` minipage?
2. Why such a behavior of `\hfill`?

Comment: There is no object for `\hfill` to push right. Use `\hfill Foo \hfill\mbox{}` then you get the desired result. You can also use `\hfil Foo`

Comment: All those `\\ ` at ends of paragraph are generating `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--20` that is infinitely bad lines. Also why `\bf` ?

Comment: `\bf` is for clarity. I didn't know that it was bad usage of `\\`. What should I do instead?

Comment: @HarishKumar, This is exactly what I've needed. If you make it an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Bold for clarity but why `\bf` which has not been defined by default in latex since 1993 and is just added to article class for backward compatibility with documents from 1980's

Comment: Never end a paragraph with `\\ ` just delete it you don't need to do anything instead.

Comment: I presume `\textbf{...}` is the preferred option then? I've learned latex on some old style files and this is what was used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place a "marker" at the end of the line where `\hfill` is used to avoid the glue being gobbled; something like `\mbox{}` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

These work as expected:

\medskip
\verb!{\dotfill{Foo}\dotfill}!\\
\adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\dotfill{Foo}\dotfill}

\medskip
\verb!{\hrulefill{Foo}\hrulefill}!\\
\adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hrulefill{Foo}\hrulefill}

\medskip
\verb!{\hfill{Foo}\hrulefill}!\\
\adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hfill{Foo}\hrulefill}

\bigskip\bigskip
These do as well:

\medskip
\verb!{\hfill{Foo}\hfill\mbox{}}!\\
\adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hfill{Foo}\hfill\mbox{}}

\medskip
\verb!{\hrulefill{Foo}\hfill\mbox{}}!\\
\adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\hrulefill{Foo}\hfill\mbox{}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
    \textbf{These work as expected:}%\\

    \vspace{2ex}

    \adjustbox{fbox,minipage=\textwidth}{\centering Foo\par}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The fact that `\par` is needed looks like a **feature** that might be worth reporting to the adjustbox author.

Comment: This is insane, but it works!